# css style overwrite order?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Well i have 2 css includes

```
<link href="Styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/ATJournal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

layout.css

```
Table.infoBox tr td table tr td
{
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```

ATJournal.css

```
table.ATJMainTable tr td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

and then we have this table

```
<Table class="infoBox">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table class="ATJMainTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    some text!
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why does layout.css overwrite ATJournal.css in this case?

Even if i change the order of the css includes "layout.css" still overwrites ATJournal.css....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The selector is more specific.

```
Table.infoBox tr td table tr td
```

is styling td cells inside a table which is inside a table classed with infobox.

```
table.ATJMainTable tr td
```

is styling td cells inside a table classed with ATJMainTable

You could use !important to override the specificity, or you could do something like:

```
table.infoBox tr td table.ATJMainTable tr td
```

to specifically override that piece.

Alternatively, can you reduce the infobox selector to be less specific?

Answer (score 10):

You can actually specify which rule wins by using `!important`.

```
table.ATJMainTable tr td
{
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    padding: 3px !important;
}
```

This basically tells the browser, that it should make sure this rule is the most important rule and all others should be cascaded in favor of this rule.

**warning:** you will want to use this sparingly because it will cause issues if that are hard to track down if you use it too much.

Comment: Are are better off trying to avoid using this syntax all together. its not bad to use it but if you can avoid it you should.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It might be a solution to the problem that inspired the question, but it's a poor one at that.

Comment: @Jasper now a few years later when i have a greater understanding of css i changed the accepted answer as this answer is no the right way to solve the problem!

Comment: @Peter It's always good to see when people take responsibility for their questions from years ago.

Answer (score 3):

it's a more specific selector.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).